# inequality, preferably using elementary methods

Tags: inequality

I was trying to prove an inequality with 3 variables, and after simplification, it boiled down to trying to prove

$$x^2 y+xz^2 +y^2 z \geq x+y+z$$, where $xyz=1$, and $x,y,z$ are all positive real numbers.

Once, I prove this I would be able to prove the overall inequality, however I am stuck at this part. The original question is supposed to be an olympiad style question, so i hope that i can prove this lemma without Lagrange Multipliers, etc.

Sincere thanks for any help!

(I have tried AM-GM, but that would lead to $x^2 y+xz^2 +y^2 z \geq 3\sqrt[3]{x^3y^3z^3}=3$ which is not sharp enough)

Comment: can you post the original problem please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: By AM-GM,
$$x^2y+x^2y+xz^2\ge 3\left(x^5y^2z^2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=3x.$$

Comment: i think you got the question incorrectly, the 2nd term in the LHS is not what the OP has given

Comment: @dineshdileep: It is just a hint rather than a full answer.